# How to update another part of the page(using PJAX)?

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

I have this code in layouts/main.php file:

```
<div class="wrap">
<? \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'nav_pjax'])?>
<?php
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'Название компании',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'ww',
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-relative',
    ],
]);

echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right', 'id' => 'ww'],
    'items' => User::getMenuItemsByRoleUser(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? Yii::$app->user : false,Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
]);
NavBar::end();
?>
<? \yii\widgets\Pjax::end()?>
<div class="container" id="content_inner">
    <? \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['timeout' => '3000'])?>
    <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
        'homeLink'=>[
            'label' => 'Главная',  // required
            'url' =>  \yii\helpers\Url::home(),      // optional, will be processed by Url::to()
        ],
        'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
    ]) ?>

    <?= $content ?>
    <? \yii\widgets\Pjax::end()?>
</div>
```

When I click into navbar link, the server returns a content, which I want to put into div class="container" id="content_inner". How I can do that? Or I should refresh the page completely?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two pjax widget, you could simply try :

**1) Update just content**

```
<div class="wrap">

        <?php /* navbar */ ?>

        <div class="container" id="content_inner">
            <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin([
                'id' => 'nav_pjax',
                'timeout' => '3000',
                'linkSelector' => '.navbar-nav a',  // use pjax on navbar links
            ]); ?>

                <?php /* breadcrumb and content */ ?>

            <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
        </div>

</div>
```

Read more about [`linkSelector`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html#$linkSelector-detail).

**2) Update navbar and content**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin([
        'id' => 'nav_pjax',
        'timeout' => '3000',
    ]); ?>

            <?php /* navbar */ ?>

            <div class="container" id="content_inner">
                <?php /* breadcrumb and content */ ?>
            </div>

    <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```